# Two tables, sort by num rows; combine?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have two tables, for this example, I'm going to call them "content" and "likes".
"Content" contains multiple entries (each one like a famous quote or something of that nature).

The site allows users to click a like button and as such, an entry is inserted into the "likes" table with the corresponding ID from the "content" table so it can traced back.

I wish to write a query that sorts the content of the "content" table by the number of likes it has in the "likes" table - is that possible? If so, how?

Many thanks and happy holidays (the second part applies even if the problem remains unresolved)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to write a query like that.

```
SELECT count(*) as total, content.*
FROM content, likes
WHERE content.id = likes.id
GROUP BY total
ORDER BY total desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM Content c, Likes l
 WHERE c.Content_Id = l.Content_Id
 GROUP BY c.Content_Id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Running a query like that every time you want to show the quotes ordered by the number of likes can become a bit intensive on the database. Have you considered adding a field to the quotes table that only keeps track of the number of likes?

That way, a query like this would suffice:

`SELECT quote FROM content ORDER BY likes DESC;`

It's somewhat creating redundancy, but not quite. Just an alternative to consider.

Comment: I'm doing that right now since I figured it might be intense, I guess in which case, I'll retain it then.

Comment: @KyleJenkins I don't know how you're doing it, but you should use an `INSERT TRIGGER` if you're not already doing so.